# pandas series get index from location

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a [pandas.Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) object `s`.

`s.iloc[5:9]` returns the following content:

```
>>> s.iloc[5:9]
date
2019-01-09    49.6
2019-01-10    79.3
2019-01-11    89.4
2019-01-14    61.7
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

Is it possible to get the index `'2019-01-09'` using `s` and its corresponding position `5`?

I mean I want a function like this:

```
>>> get_index_by_position(s, 5)
'2019-01-09'
>>> get_index_by_position(s, 6)
'2019-01-10'
>>> get_index_by_position(s, 8)
'2019-01-14'
```

How can I implement `get_index_by_position()`?

Comment: kindly share  a sample data representing ur question

Comment: try s.reset_index(), then you can access `2019-01-09` using s and its corresponding position 5.

Comment: @jezrael I'm using `pandas.Series`, not `pandas.DataFrame`.

Comment: `s.index.get_loc(5)` returns `KeyError: 5`. I tried `str(target_price.index[5])`, then found it works.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your hint. :-)

Comment: hups, you are right, just tested.